# How do you get "matlab style" function output in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

My question is specific to the first line in a matlab function

```
function [a, b, c, d] = somefunction(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    % Some mangoes and pears
end
```

specifically to the left hand side of that equality. In this way matlab (I think?) ensures the output is a that vector. I know in Python you can achieve the same thing by assembling the results of your computations into an array. Is there a way you can get this "shortcut" method in python? Something like this (but obviously not exactly this):

```
def somefunction(arg1,arg2,arg3) = [a, b, c, d]:
# some apples and bananas
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python (AFAIK) you define the return value using `return` command.

So in Matlab

```
function [a, b, c, d] = foo( a1, a2 )
% apples banabs, and most importantly assignment to outputs:
a = ...
b = ...
c = ...
d = ...
return;   % return has no arguments in Matlab
```

While in python:

```
def foo( a1, a2 ) :
    % apples bananas
    return a, b, c, d # outputs are defined here
```

If you want your outputs as a tupple you may do it explicitly

```
    return ( a, b, c, d )
```

Comment: So the only thing it does in matlab to say [vector]=somefunction(args), is to "placehold" the value to return?

Comment: @NormanB yes. This: `a, b = function( a1, a2 )` is a syntax error in Matlab. You'll have to write `[a, b] = function( a1, a2 )`.

Comment: I fear that `return a, b, c, d` and `return (a, b, c, d)` are exactly the same thing only with more parentheses. Both return a tuple.

Comment: @Hyperboreus How many arguments do you assign the output to? `t = foo( a1, a2 )` or `a, b, c, d = foo(a1, a2)`?

Comment: @Shai Doesn't make any difference. `type(foo(a1,a2))` is `tuple`. So in your first example `t` will be a tuple, and in your second example it will get unpacked. At least with `def f (): return 1,2,3` and `def g(): return (1,2,3)` the return type is the same.